# Starting position for iOS path/curve animation

Tags: ios, animation, path, cgpath

I'm animating an object using this code:

```
CGRect imageFrame = objectToAnimate.frame;
CGPoint viewOrigin;
viewOrigin.y = imageFrame.origin.y + imageFrame.size.height/2;
viewOrigin.x = imageFrame.origin.x + imageFrame.size.width/2;

objectToAnimate.layer.position = viewOrigin;

// Set up path movement
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, viewOrigin.x, viewOrigin.y);
CGPathAddArc(curvedPath, NULL, viewOrigin.x-[radius intValue], viewOrigin.y, [radius intValue], 0, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(115), NO);
pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
pathAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

//Animate one curve
[objectToAnimate.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"curvedFalling"];
```

Everything works as it should.

When I call a similar animation on the same object again, the object moves back to its original starting position and then animates. How can I have it begin animation from the spot where it ended up after the first animation?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/9900928#9900928

Answer (score 0):

`objectToAnimate.frame` is not being changed here. You must have to update the frame here after the animation finished because it's being used as source for next animations. to have this at the end of this code use this:

```
.
.
.

//Animate one curve
[objectToAnimate.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"curvedFalling"];
 objectToAnimate.frame.origin.x = viewOrigin.x;
 objectToAnimate.frame.origin.y = viewOrigin.y;
```